# Force Nuget package to use specific version of sub dependency?

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

When installing the two Nuget packages Hl7.Fhir.DSTU2 and Hl7.Fhir.R4, we get something like this:

[image]

The package DSTU2 seems to have issues using Hl7.Fhir.Support.Poco version 3.4.0.
If we install DSTU2 on it's own, all packages are using the version 1.9.0.

Is there a way in the .csproj file to specify sub dependencies versions and have the .dll installed in specific folders?

Here are the 3.4.0 versions .dll in my debug folder

[image]

Comment: Did you try installing the dependent package with the version you need? E.G if X is using specific version of Y install Y separately on top.

Comment: We did and if we use the lower version, R4 gives errors saying its dependency is too low.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you just add a `PackageReference` in your project for the transitive dependency as well. NuGet picks a single version to use for each package you depend on, and if you have a direct reference to a package then NuGet will always pick this version due to its [nearest wins rule](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution#nearest-wins).

As you've spotted though, this can't be a lower version than any of your dependencies require themselves, or you get a [package downgrade error](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/errors-and-warnings/nu1605). This is intentional - if you reference `packageA` which says it needs at least a particular version of `packageB`, then given that you can only use one version of each package it stands to reason that you need at least that version of `packageB`.